# Running a grunt task on one Gruntfile from another

Tags: gruntjs

I have a Gruntfile in the root of my project. I also have jQuery installed via Bower in an app/components/jquery directory.

As part of my Gruntfile I'd like to run some commands on the jQuery Gruntfile to build a custom version of the library.

How can I get at their Gruntfile from mine?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a simple task that [spawns grunt](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.spawn) in the folder you want:

```
grunt.registerTask('run-grunt', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    grunt.util.spawn({
        grunt: true,
        args: [''],
        opts: {
            cwd: 'app/components/jquery'
        }
    }, function (err, result, code) {
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: This almost works.... What would be needed for this to show the output from the task. Let's say I have a task karma:unit that runs my unit tests with `watch:true`. I'd like to be able to run it and see the output on screen.

Comment: If you want to see it streaming you will have to spin up your own child process https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html and respond to the data events - otherwise just output the result to the console `console.log(result.stdout);`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to get console output, building on @Sindre's answer, all you have to do is console log the result.stdout.

```
grunt.registerTask('run-grunt', function() {
    var cb = this.async();
    grunt.util.spawn({
        grunt: true,
        args: ['clean', 'copy:fonts'],
        opts: {
            cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap'
        }
    }, function(error, result, code) {
        console.log(result.stdout);
        cb();
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, though of course the output is buffered.

Answer (score 11):

Based on @Sindre's and @Stephen's answer, we can also get the console output "in real time" without being buffered:

```
grunt.registerTask('run-grunt', function() {
  var cb = this.async();
  var child = grunt.util.spawn({
      grunt: true,
      args: ['clean', 'copy:fonts'],
      opts: {
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap'
      }
  }, function(error, result, code) {
      cb();
  });

  child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
});
```

Comment: Works good, also in Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer.
Now I can run tasks from the Bootstrap gruntfile via a gruntfile in the root of the project (which is needed for Task Runner Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

dont know if that works, but you could give it a try. your jQuery Gruntfile is exported via "module.exports". that should mean, that you can require it in your code and use it.

```
var jQueryGrunt = require('path-to-jquery-gruntfile');
jQueryGrunt.task.run(['your-task-you-want-to-run']);
```

will be interesting to hear if that works...