# Grunt task to clone/checkout a git project

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I'm working on a project that is built using **grunt**. It depends on an external repo (https://github.com/facebook/xctool) that I would like to clone/pull during `npm install` or `grunt mySetupTask`.

I've seen trails of a `grunt-gitco` plugin at http://gruntjs.com/plugins/checkout, but it does not seem to be available.

Any good starting point for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either set up a [npm postinstall script](https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) in your package.json:

```
{
    "name": "mypackage",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "git clone git://github.com/facebook/xctool.git"
    }
}
```

Or use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to execute the command to clone the repo:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        gitclone: {
            command: 'git clone git://github.com/facebook/xctool.git'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: grunt-shell has indeed helped me solve other problems (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711058/running-a-grunt-task-on-one-gruntfile-from-another) that I was facing in this Gruntfile. Thanks a lot for your plugin!

Comment: FYI: Your `initConfig` object is missing a closing brace (specifically the `shell` property object). SO won't let me make the change since it has a 6 character minimum for edits.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a Grunt plugin for this. Not sure if it was available at the time. I'm still having some issues getting it working.

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-git

```
gitclone:
  clone:
    options:
      repository: "https://github.com/imaginethepoet/autojqm"
      branch: "master"
      directory: "repo"
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you know that `npm install` support git URLs?

```
npm install git://github.com/facebook/xctool.git
```

[Docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that. Unfortunately, the prerequisite repo is not a module with its package.json file, but something completely unrelated to node.js. npm is not happy with that.