# Run grunt task from another gruntfile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I'm trying to figure out how I can watch one of my `less` files, and when that file updates, trigger the `Gruntfile.js` in `/bootstrap` and run it's `less` function.

I'm building something out that requires me to use bootstrap but not disturb anything in the bootstrap folder other than adding one `@include` in `bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less`, so that I can use bootstraps less variables and functions in style overrides and have all styles in one css file.

Comment: Why can't you use something like grunt-watch to fire a task from the original?  I'm confused why you need two?

Comment: What I'm making needs to be exist outside of bootstrap, so my less files exist outside of the bootstrap folder and everything. This way what I can hand off this project and peeps can use any bootstrap build they want with it. So if I had my own grunt file that watches my less for changes, and when they're made it run's bootstraps compile process, all would be good.

Note: I ended up separating my overrides from bootstrap entirely. This means two style sheets have to be loaded instead of one, but made things easier to manage. Would still like to know how to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this question perhaps this link will answer your question: [Running a grunt task on one Gruntfile from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711058/running-a-grunt-task-on-one-gruntfile-from-another)